# PI compensator question

Tags: control, pid-controller

I have a RLC circuit to discover the characteristics of controlled system.
The block diagram has shown below

[image]

where [image]

If I add a PI compensator to the closed loop system, Q(s)=1/s,and the transfer function of the system becomes[image]. I’m wondering for which K the system will produce a response that has smallest overshoot. Is there there any correlation between the damping  and the value of K?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me

Answer (score 1):

First: $$Q = 1/s$$ is only an integral, not a PI. You want $$1 + \frac{1}{T_is}$$ so that your compensator is given by

$$
PI(s) = K + \frac{K}{T_is}
$$

and you actually have some way to tune both terms independently. The CLTF is then

$$H_{CL}(s) = \frac{PI(s)P(s)}{1+PI(s)P(s)}.$$

Since the overshoot will be determined by the damping of the complex poles, you need to find the root locus of $$1+PI(s)P(s)$$ and choose some value for K which minimizes the damping; the root locus can be overlayed with lines of constant damping ratio to make it easy to see which roots are within your allowable range. SISOtool in Matlab makes this pretty easy to do.